# Use variable in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Create_Subjects]
    @Subj_ID nvarchar(9)
AS
    DECLARE @First3Digits nvarchar(3);
    DECLARE @Result int;

    -- Fetching the first 3 digits of the subject
    SET @First3Digits = SUBSTRING(@Subj_ID,1,3);

    -- Check if view is present or not
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.views WHERE Name = @First3Digits)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'View exists'
        -- checking if the subject is present in the view
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @First3Digits WHERE SubjectName = @Subj_ID)
        BEGIN
            SET @Result = 1;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @Result = 0;
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Create a view as view doesn't exist
        EXEC('create view' + @First3Digits 
            + 'as 
                    (select SubjectName from dbo.Subjects where SubjectName like '+@First3Digits+'%'+');')

        SET @Result = 0;
        PRINT 'view does not exist'
    END

    PRINT @First3Digits
GO;
```

In the above code I am getting issues on the line

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @First3Digits WHERE SubjectName = @Subj_ID)
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: If you intend to write dynamic sql, then you need to SEE the statement you generate. Do that and you will discover one problem.

Comment: Since `@First3Digits` isn't a table variable, but _might_ contain the name of a table, you'll need to make your problem statement dynamic SQL. Although three characters as used appears to preclude too much fun, see [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) before going too far down the dynamic SQL rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @First3Digits WHERE SubjectName = @Subj_ID)
```

is broken because `@First3Digits` is the name of a table (I assume - even though its only `nvarchar(3)`!) and cannot be used directly in a query like that, instead you need to use dynamic SQL, specifically [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as follows:

```
PRINT 'View exists'

declare @Sql nvarchar(max);

set @Sql = 'select @Result = case when exists (select 1 from dbo.' + quotename(@First3Digits) + ' where SubjectName = ''' + @Subj_ID + ''') then 1 else 0 end';

execute sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Result bit out', @Result = @Result out; 

-- @Result is now set as required
```

Note the use of [`quotename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to protect against SQL injection.

As an aside, on the face of it, your design looks highly in need of improvement. Creating a view per `Subject` (whatever that actually is) seems flawed, prone to maintenance issues and scalability issues. There is probably a better way.

Comment: It's curious that you assemble `@sql` with `... ' where SubjectName = ''' + @Subj_ID + ''') ...` and then pass `@Subj_ID` as a parameter, though there is no reference to it in the dynamic SQL statement. Is that to allow its use for SQL injection?

Comment: @HABO very curious :) - wasn't paying enough attention :) removed now.